# kmz mismatch in the Google Maps API v3 and Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, overlay, kmz

I have some kmz files(exported from ArcMap). They overlay perfect with the base maps of Google Earth, but when it applied to Google Maps API, they mismatch the base maps. Can anyone give me some clues?

[image: Default Layout]

[image: After Zoom In/Out]

Comment: can you show screenshots of the mismatch?

Comment: It is okay with the default. But after zoom in/out, it messed up. I guess I have to reload the kmz each time after I zoomed In/Out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there was a conflict of names with my template. It has nothing to do with the google maps api lib or arcpy lib.